# JasperReports CSV export

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using iReport 2.0.2. I want to suppress page headers and footers while exporting to CSV alone but not in any other format. Can anyone please let me know how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the **[net.sf.jasperreports.export.{format}.exclude.origin.{suffix}.{arbitrary_name}](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.%7Bformat%7D.exclude.origin.%7Bsuffix%7D.%7Barbitrary_name%7D)** report's property.

The snippet of *jrxml* file for excluding *pageHeader* and *pageFooter* bands from the resulting *csv* file:

```xml
<jasperReport ...>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.band.1" value="pageHeader"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.band.2" value="pageFooter"/>
```

These properties only affect the *csv* exporter in this sample. For example, the *pdf* document will be with two bands (page header and footer).

It works for *iReport 4.x*. I did not check it for 2.x version.

---

The additional info available in [How can I suppress page headers and footers when exporting to XLS?](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/jasperreports-library-faq#How_can_I_suppress_page_headers_and_footers_when_exporting_to_XLS) topic of FAQ at *http://community.jaspersoft.com*.

Comment: Oh Thank you. I am using jasperreports.properties file and in that I tried using the same. net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.exclude.first.band.1=pageFooter.                                                                                                                   
net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.band.2=pageHeader

Comment: @Giri Just add note about iReport version

Comment: @Giri You should add properties to jrxml file. It is work for me. I'm using the `iReport 4.1.3 `.

Comment: I am using iReport2.0.2. If it works for 4.x ,Can you please let me know how to do that in Jrxml file?. I will try that and maybe it might work for me too.Thanks

Comment: @Giri You should add this two lines (with properties) after the `jasperReport` root element in the jrxml file. Like in my sample - it is the header of jrxml file

Comment: Thanks Alex. It doesn't work for me in this version. Is there any other way that you know that would work in version 2.0?.

Comment: @Giri You can override the Exporter class and use it